# Rounding price number in java

Tags: java, rounding

I'm new to java programming. I would like to round up a price to the nearest 2 decimal places with a multiple of 5.

***Eg.***

- `38.80` stays the same.
- `38.81` to `38.80`.
- `38.82` to `38.80`.
- `38.83` to `38.85`.
- `38.84` to `38.85`.
- `38.85` stays the same.
- `38.86` to `38.85`.
- `38.87` to `38.85`.
- `38.88` to `38.90`.
- `38.89` to `38.90`.
- `38.90` stays the same.

I tried the provided duplicates but they come out only to 1 decimal place.
Eg. `38.82` to `38.8`.

This is my code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class RoundUp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double num = 38.84;
        System.out.println(df.format(Math.round(num*10.00)/10.00));
    }
}
```

I have looked into other model answers by experts in this web but none of them really answer my question. Setting into 2 decimal places, I'm using `DemicalFormat`. That I know, but rounding the number, let's say 38.83 to 38.85 and 38.87 to 38.90 is what I really want. 
It is a rounding system that my country is using. Can check it out [here](http://www.bnm.gov.my/index.php?ch=en_rounding&pg=en_rounding_content&ac=567).

**

> This question has been answer by @Mureinik  double rounded =
>   Math.round(num * 100.0 / 5.0) * 5.0 / 100.0;

**

Comment: You have 2 separate problems here... probably should have been two questions? (1) You want to round to 1 decimal place, **except** when the second decimal place is a 5. That's not a normal way to round, so no, your code isn't going to do that—you're just calling the library function `Math.round()`, which of course is going to do something more normal. (2) You want to **print** your number with 2 decimal places, and it's not doing that for you.

Comment: if I dont use Math.round(), do you have any suggestion? Sorry to say but this rounding system exist in my country.. so jz gotta follow right?

Comment: It's the sentence near the bottom that says that 38.87 goes to 38.90 that confused me about your rounding system. I understand now, with your edit showing that 38.87 goes to 38.85. You're rounding to the nearest 0.05.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use BigDecimal instead of double when you are dealing with money.

And then it would be like

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(38.84);
value = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

You can refer [Javadocs for ROUND_HALF_UP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP) and [setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20java.math.RoundingMode))

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your recommendation. Totally appreciate it. But slight problem here... when i tried to use your code.. it doesn't round up..

Comment: @Wilz5363:- Can yo utry with: `value = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)`

Comment: nope....still remain as 38.84 @Rahul

Comment: @Wilz5363:- And what about 38.87?

Comment: :- this the code i used..
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(38.84);
value = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
System.out.println(value);

Comment: :- it doesnt change anything...sorry man..

Comment: @Wilz5363:- Dont be sorry. Try with `BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(38.84); value = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN); System.out.println(value);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79779/discussion-between-wilz5363-and-rahul-tripathi).